# ImageMagick or Ghostscript: Create Image from PDF

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm working on a big problem: I have to create a perfect colored JPEG from a PDF file. But there still small differences in green or blue color. I'm using Ghostscript version 8.71 on a Debian system.

Original PDF file:

- http://content.test.de/configurations/82/e2/82e2897f5448e73769655317e8fdee77/output.pdf

The simple way via

```
convert output.pdf -density 600 -quality 100 output.jpg
```

Result:

- http://content.test.de/configurations/82/e2/82e2897f5448e73769655317e8fdee77/output-0.jpg

creates a very light green having nothing to do with the color in the PDF.

After that I tried two other ways with better results, but not perfect:

Via ImageMagick:

```
convert output.pdf -profile sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc \
                   -density 600 -quality 100 test.jpg

convert -profile ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc -profile eciRGB_v2.icc \
        -quality 100 test-1.jpg finish-1.png
```

Result: Links like before with filename "finish-0.png" (I can just write two links).

Via Ghostscript:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=237 \
   -sOutputFile=image%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=95 -dUseCIEColor -g850x610 \
   -dPDFFitPage -r300 -q output.pdf -c quit
```

Result: Links like before with filename "image1.jpg" (I can just write two links).

Anybody has an idea to get a perfect result?

Answer (score 1):

First, use a recent version of Ghostscript, 8.71 is 3 years old. Versions prior to 9.0 will use standard PostScript colour conversions, 9.0 onwards use Little CMS. Your PDF file uses ICC profile based colour spaces with 3 components (RGB), PostScritp RGB->CMYK is fast but inaccurate, so best not to do that.

I believe that if you use a decently up to date version you will find the results adequate without any further tweaking. Do NOT use -dUseCIEColor! That's a horrible PostScript kludge.

It also looks like the jpegcmyk device isn't doing proper colour management, is there a reason you can't use the jpeg device ?

Comment: Without dUseCIEColor the result is more uglier. I don't know if it's possible to update our system to version 9.0 or higher. Is it available for debian? With jpegcmyk the result is better than just with the jpeg device. That's the only reason I used it.

Comment: Using jpegcmyk forces a colour conversion (the images in the original are RGB) which results in your colour problem. Ghostscript is open source, so you can build it yourself.

Comment: You haven't specified a command line, so I can't compare results. 9.05 is *still* nearly 18 months out of date, I would use the current code (which is about to be 9.09). without looking at the files in some detail I can't be absolutely certain, but you need to be aware that if you are looking at a PDF file, the input colour may well be getting converted (and colour managed) by the PDF viewing application to be correct for your (presumably RGB) monitor. A different application viewing CMYK may make a different conversion to RGB and hence the colours would appear different